# Filter out rows in a SQL Server table based on added-on-date

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table in my SQL Server which I update on a monthly basis with new data from the Client. Unfortunately, there is no timestamp which tells me when the rows were added or modified. This becomes a problem when sometimes the same data gets appended twice, and I need to manually check and delete the repeated rows. Is there a way to write a query like below:

```
DELETE FROM (table)
WHERE (date_time_when_row_is_added) <= (manually_specified_datetime)
```

Comment: Only if you add a column to store the datetime that the row was added or updated. There is no magic way to do it.

Comment: is there anything else unique about the record that you are inserting. I.E. like a primary key field? If yes.. then you can do an insert of all records that do not exist in the destination and then an update of the records in the destination that are already present..

Comment: Refer https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/delete-duplicates-sql-server/ to delete duplicate records from a table.